Recurrence relation for integer sequences raised to the power of $n$
An interesting pattern can be observed when considering a sequence of positive integers raised to some power $n$.
When a sequence of continuous integers $i$ (of length >=n) is raised to the power of $n$, the ${i+1}^{th}$ element can be expressed as a linear combination of the previous $n$ numbers.
For $n$ = 2:

$x_{i+1}$ = $x_{i}$ + ($x_{i} - x_{i-1}$) + $n$!

For $n$ = 3:

$x_{i+1}$ = $x_{i}$ + ($x_{i} - x_{i-1}$) + (($x_{i} - x_{i-1}$) - ($x_{i-1} - x_{i-2})$) + $n$!

I am not sure how to express it concisely for larger $n$, but it seems to hold for any $n$.
How it can be computed for larger $n$ can be seen in the second example.
In short, you compute the continuous difference triangle of depth $n$, sum the right diagonal (last element of each row), and add a factorial of n.
First Example (powers of 3)
This is more easily expressed graphically as follows:
Suppose we want to compute the next element in the list of integers 1,2,3 raised to the power of 3, that is, which element comes after 1, 9, 27.
We compute a continuous differences triangle (of depth $n$, in this case 3) as follows:
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
& & & 1& & 8& & 27 & & \\
& & & & 7 & & 19& & & \\
& & & & & 12 & & & & \\
\end{array}
Sum the last elements in each row, and add $n!$, we get the next element in the sequence ($4^3$):

27 + 19 + 12 + 3! = 67

Second Example (powers of 5)
Suppose we have an integer sequence: ${1,2,3,4,5}$ which when raised to power of $5$ would be ${1, 32, 243, 1024, 3125}$. The next element of this sequence, that is 10^5 can be computed as a sum of the last values of each rows plus 5!:
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
& 1 && 32 & & 243 & & 1024 & & 3125 & & \\
& & 31 & & 211 & & 781 & & 2101 & \\
& & & 180 & & 570 & & 1320 & & \\
& & & & 390 & & 750 & & & \\
& & & & & 360 & & & & \\
\end{array}
6^5 = 3125 + 2101 + 1320 + 360 + 750 + 5!
Code
The following code can be used to compute new elements in the sequence of integers raised to some power:

https://gist.github.com/emuskardin/0d14053880378a47fca06cded7d36a5a

It is not too user-friendly atm, but you can check that with this method we can compute sequences of powers of $n$ for any $n$.
Does anyone know why this happens? Does a proof exist?

Hint: you might find it useful to gather the terms in your expressions. For example, your $n=3$ case can be written $x_{i+1}=3x_i-3x_{i-1}+x_{i-2}+n!$. What pattern can you see in the coefficients?

Reminds me of a time in 5th grade when a teacher started putting the sequence n^2 up and asking us to find the pattern.  I  noticed the differences are (1+2); (2+3); (3+4):...   .  I didn't think at the time to see what the differences are for n^3 but now I will!  It starts with 7 and the differences are 12,18, 24, 30, ....  .   Deceptively simple.
